# Why does Pandas returns a function object when accessing a column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I assign value to a multiindex dataframe `df` with `loc` but for some reason when I access the data it returns a `method` object, not the data. Why does it happen and how can I get the data ?

```
price = 100
df.loc['ABC', ('price', 'spot', 'last')] = price
df.loc['DEF', ('price', 'spot', 'last')] = price + 1

type(df.price.spot)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(df.price.spot.last)
method

df.price.spot.last.sum()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Comment: @enke `balances` is a dataframe

Comment: DataFrames have `last` method, so using `.` notation, that method is called first. To access the column, you have to use the brackets: `df.price.spot['last']`

Comment: `last` is a method. `last()` is a _call_ to that method

Comment: It's encouraged never to use the `df.column` notation, and always `df['column']` that is unambiguous